# Wireshark - listening SQL Queries but no values

Tags: sql, firebird, wireshark

I wonder if it's possible to log an entire query to Firebird 3.0 DB Server using Wireshark. I'm able to log some of communication, but I see queries with question tags instead of values.

`select * from SP_procedure_name(?,?,?)`

I don't see any packet that could have transported these values. Is this some type of database communication encryption? Is there any way to disable this and see exact provided values?

Answer (score 3):

In the Firebird wire protocol a statement handle is allocated (`op_allocate_statement`), a statement is prepared on that handle (`op_prepare_statement`), and then you can execute that statement multiple times with different sets of values for the bind parameters (`op_execute`/`op_execute2`).

So the packet you see in the wireshark trace with the statement is only the statement prepare step. To see the values you need to look at the `op_execute` (or `op_execute2`) packets. The Firebird wire protocol is binary, so apart from string values you will not easily see other types of values (iirc the wireshark dissector doesn't decode this).

It is not possible to disable this, because this is a fundamental part of how the Firebird protocol works.

If you want to check parameters used on execute, you should consider looking at the Firebird trace facility.